# sound not playing in python, turtle for a pong game im making (mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, python-turtle, pong

I have been following a tutorial on how to make a pong game with python using turtle. The tutorial was 3 years ago, and I'm using the latest version, however everything has been working fine so far. My issue is with getting the sound to play.

I do have the audio file in the same folder as my pong game, I have imported OS, I did exactly what the video said however it still is not playing. For reference, its this video at around timestamp 39:56 https://youtu.be/XGf2GcyHPhc?t=2396

other details that may or may not be useful is that I am running MacOS Ventura 13.2.1, and I'm running python v3.11.2

this is what my code looks like:

```
if ball.ycor() > 290:
    ball.sety(290)
    ball.dy *= -1
    os.system("afplay bounce.wav&")
```

Comment: I recommend minimizing your code. If your entire script is `import os; os.system("afplay bounce.wav&")` and it still doesn't work, then you can remove all of your turtle code and the corresponding tags and we can talk about whether your system has `afplay` and so forth (please share any errors). If it does work, then the problem is likely with the turtle code--that branch is probably not being reached when you think it is--it's not a sound or system problem. In that case, please share a [mcve] of the turtle code necessary for others to run and observe the error. Thanks.

Comment: ggorlen, the issue is that I am trying to only play the sound when the ball hits the horizontal edge of the screen, or when it hits the target. I am not really sure how to simplify my code more-

Comment: I believe I understand the question and have suggested a procedure above for how to simplify it. Can you try running the sound without turtle and confirm if it works?

Comment: How is this a question about python-turtle? Surely it's about getting audio to play, just while doing python-turtle.